# How to manipulate certain windows for an application in Java

Tags: java, windows, automation, awtrobot

Basically I'm writing a program for a game in Java to do self automation for certain tasks. I'm not exactly sure how I can pull off certain things to my liking though.

Most tasks would be clicking certain areas and entering text. I understand most of this can be done with java.awt.Robot..

However, my question is two things.

1)How can I go about performing these tasks in said window for the game without using my mouse and keyboard. That way I can just minimize or put the game to the side while the program does its automation.This game is a java application if that helps.

2)I'm using Opencv for image recognition to see if a certain task is completed by analyzing a small area of the window. Is there a way to specify with java.awt.Robot which section of the screen I want to take a picture of?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using java.awt.Robot class you can perform things like moving mouse, pressing keyboard keys and take screen shots of your screen and you can't perform background tasks.

```
public class TestRobot {

Robot ro;
Image img;

public TestRobot(){

    ro.mouseMove(100, 200); // move mouse to specific point

    ro.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK ); //mouse click
    ro.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK ); // mouse release

    ro.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F1); //press F1
    ro.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F1); //release F1

    img = ro.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())); // take screen shot 
    }
}
```